# Quicksorting a cType array of numbers

Tags: python, ctypes, quicksort

I'm trying to implement a couple sorting methods on a ctypes array of integers in Python 3, and can't seem to figure out the Quicksort method. I believe the majority of my code is correct, but I'm just missing a silly statement. Right now all I'm getting when I try and print the array this returns to is a 'NoneType' object.

Thanks so much.

```
#Quicksort Algorithm
def quicksort(list):
    n = len(list)
    return recquick(list, 0, n-1)

#Recursive Quicksort Function
def recquick(list, first, last):
    #Base Case
    if first >= last:
        return
    else:
        #Save pivot value
        pivot = list[first]

        pos = partseq(list, first, last)

        #Repeat the process on the two subsequences
        recquick(list, first, pos-1)
        recquick(list, pos+1, last)

#Partitions subsequence using first key as pivot
def partseq(list, first, last):
    #Save pivot value
    pivot = list[first]

    #Find pivot position and move elements around the pivot
    left = first + 1
    right = last
    while left <= right:
        #Find the first key larger than the pivot
        while left < right and list[left] < pivot:
            left += 1

        #find the last key in the sequence that is smaller than the pivot
        while right >= left and list[right] >= pivot:
            right -= 1


        #Swap the two keys
        if left < right:
            tmp = list[left]
            list[left] = list[right]
            list[right] = tmp

        #Put the pivot in the proper position
        if right != first:
            list[first] = list[right]
            list[right] = pivot

        #Return index position of the pivot value
        return right
```

Comment: Is pointing out that `quicksort` does not have a return statement (and thus returns `None`) redundant? :P

Comment: Yeah, sorry, even if I change it to `return recquick(list, 0, n-1)` the problem stays.

Comment: Well, at that point, `recquick` never returns the list. Your code seems to sort the list 'in place', if you check the list you inserted, does it happen to be sorted (or at least different from when you function started)?

Comment: No. It's a shuffled list from 1-10. :(

Answer (score 1):

Your outer while loop is not proper in `partseq`. The swapping of right and pivot should occur only once outside of while loop. The return statement should also be outside the while

Also based on [This link](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/~ddd/cis3020/summer-97/lectures/lec17/sld002.htm), I made small adjustments to the algorithm

- `left` starts at `first`
- The first inner while loop runs till `list[left] <= pivot` and the second inner while loop runs till `list[right] > pivot`

> ```
> #Quicksort Algorithm
> def quicksort(list):
>     n = len(list)
>     return recquick(list, 0, n-1)
>
> #Recursive Quicksort Function
> def recquick(list, first, last):
>     #Base Case
>     if first >= last:
>         return
>     else:
>         #Save pivot value
>         pivot = list[first]
>
>         pos = partseq(list, first, last)
>
>         #Repeat the process on the two subsequences
>         recquick(list, first, pos-1)
>         recquick(list, pos+1, last)
>
> #Partitions subsequence using first key as pivot
> def partseq(list, first, last):
>     #Find pivot position and move elements around the pivot
>     pivot = list[first]
>
>     left = first 
>     right = last
>     while left<right: 
>         #Find the first key larger than the pivot
>
>         while left < right and list[left] <= pivot:
>             left += 1
>
>         #find the last key in the sequence that is smaller than the pivot
>         while right >= left and list[right] > pivot:
>             right -= 1
>
>         #Swap the two keys
>         if left < right:
>             tmp = list[left]
>             list[left] = list[right]
>             list[right] = tmp
>
>
>     #Put the pivot in the proper position
>     #right to left
>     if right != first:
>         list[first] = list[right]
>         list[right] = pivot
>
>     #Return index position of the pivot value
>     return right
> ```

The result

```
>>> import try1
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,]
>>> try1.quicksort(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a=[6,5,4,3,2,1,]
>>> try1.quicksort(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a=[1]
>>> try1.quicksort(a)
>>> a
[1]
>>> a=[]
>>> try1.quicksort(a)
>>> a
[]
>>> a=[43,76,9,10,1,15,62,]
>>> try1.quicksort(a)
>>> a
[1, 9, 10, 15, 43, 62, 76]
```